# How to keep the equation editor centred as part of a list, without also centring the list numbers

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I'm trying to type numbered lists of physics equations in Microsoft Word 2016, but cannot for the life of me get it to stop left justifying the equations and undoing my alignment at the equals sign. Is there a way to fix this or am I just SOL? I'm trying to get something like this:

```
1.                                  2+2=4  
                                    2+3=5  
2.                                  2+4=6
```

I only need the equals alignment to remain steady within a single list level, so if, for example, the 2+4=6 doesn't align perfectly with the two equations above it that's fine, so long as the 2+2=4 and the 2+3=5 align. Thank you!

Comment: You could use a table with two columns, the first for your numbered list, and the second for your equations.

Comment: Make the table's borders invisible though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the equations each on their own line with nothing else, you can select them, right click and chose 'align at ='.

Then you need to add the numbering. One option is to add a new type of Caption called Equation in the line above, and use that to number and label the equation sets, eg:

[image]

Another, more manual route, is to insert the equation sets the way you probably currently are. For anything not on a row with anything else, select and align as per example 1 above. To get the first line of each set to align with the others, put a tab between the index and the equation, and use move the tab marker to an appropriate spot. If necessary, do fine adjustment by adding a space in front of the equation, and changing the font size of the space up or down:

[image]